# How to extract part of a file name to a text file?

Tags: r

I have several files in a directory `data`.

these files are named like this:

```
  file_file_sd_daf_800_800_log-(3-got)_20100101_20121012
```

All files share all parts of the name but differ with part `sd`.

I want to extract only this part of file name as one column and write out to text file .

I list all file like this:

```
   dir<- list.files("C:\\data", "*.txt", full.names = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, this should work (using regular expressions):

```
dir_ <- list.files("C:\\data", "*.txt", full.names = TRUE)

tmp <- regmatches(dir_, regexec("file_file_(.+)_daf.+", dir_))
sapply(tmp, "[", 2)
```

a little test with your example:

```
x <- "file_file_sd_daf_800_800_log-(3-got)_20100101_20121012"
regmatches(x, regexec("file_file_(.+)_daf.+", x))[[1]][2]

# [1] "sd"
```

you can then write the different bits you get to a file by using `write`.